# cant join tables HABTM and many to one ,cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I cant use a join to get the required data from the table relationship of

Student HABTM Subject, and 
Guardian 1 to many Student

Without giving all the code,my find gets the required data but it adds another table (AvailabilityForStudent)which has a HABTM relationship with Student, along with other fields. I simply get too much data.
I have to add Guardian2 to the Guardian table to avoid a conflict which i dont understand.

What is the correct join to display data from 3 tables only?

```
   $students = $this->find('all', array(
            'joins'=>$joins,
                'conditions'    => $conditions,
              'fields'=> $fields,

              'order'=>$order,
            ));


      $joins = array(

                 array('table' => 'students_subjects',
                            'alias' => 'StudentsSubject',
                            'type' => 'LEFT',
                            'conditions' => array(
                            'Student.id=StudentsSubject.student_id',
                     )
                     ),     
                array('table' => 'subjects',
                            'alias' => 'Subject',
                            'type' => 'LEFT',
                            'conditions' => array(
                            'StudentsSubject.subject_id=Subject.id',
                     )
                     ),
               array('table' => 'guardians',
                    'alias' => 'Guardian2',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                    'Student.guardian_id=Guardian2.id',
                     )
                     ),

                );



    (int) 0 => array(
        'Student' => array(
            'id' => '267',
            'last_name' => 'xxx',
            'first_name' => 'xxx',
            'address_suburb' => 'xxx',
            'student_inactive' => false,
            'student_mobile' => '0'
        ),
        'Guardian' => array(
            'guardian_last_name' => 'xx',
            'guardian_first_name' => 'xxxx',
            'id' => '267',
            'guardian_mobile' => 'xxxx',
            'guardian_email' => 'xx@yahoo.com.au'
        ),
        'Subject' => array(
            'name' => 'English: Year 7 - 10',
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '9',
                'name' => 'English: Year 7 - 10',
                'StudentsSubject' => array(
                    'id' => '1079',
                    'student_id' => '267',
                    'subject_id' => '9',
                    'created' => null,
                    'modified' => null
                )
            )
        ),
        'StudentsSubject' => array(
            'id' => '1079'
        ),
        'AvailabilityForStudent' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
```

Update- added this line $this->recursive = -1 instead of $this->Student->recursive = -1; and it works

Comment: is this even possible ? Would it be easier to do a HABTM find on the subject table and then do another find for each result on the guardian table?

Answer (score 0):

Update- added this line $this->recursive = -1 instead of $this->Student->recursive = -1; and it works